# File gets uploaded but then incorrect URL is displayed in API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The working part looks this way:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file)
```

The method is defined as:

```
def upload_file(instance, filename):
   return '{user}/{filename}'.format(user=instance.user, filename=filename)
```

In `settings.py` I have the following paths set:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
(...)
# For reference:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

After uploading a file through admin interface there is a success message and the file appears in `static/media/admin/<file>` location. The `static` directory is in `BASE_DIR`, at the same level as `db.sqlite3` mentioned in the excerpt above.

However, when displaying image location in API, I'm getting something like:

```
"file": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/admin/<file>"
```

As you clearly see, the `static` directory is skipped and I get 404 after clicking the link.

What should be fixed to make it work in Django 2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following code to app's `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

And then to append this line to `urlpatterns` array:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```